# Beautiful People - Dynamic programming

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve Beautiful People Question at http://acm.sgu.ru/problem.php?contest=0&problem=199 but I am getting wrong answer in some testcase.

> The most prestigious sports club in one city has exactly N members.
>   Each of its members is strong and beautiful. More precisely, i-th
>   member of this club (members being numbered by the time they entered
>   the club) has strength Si and beauty Bi . Since this is a very
>   prestigious club, its members are very rich and therefore
>   extraordinary people, so they often extremely hate each other.
>   Strictly speaking, i-th member of the club Mr X hates j-th member of
>   the club Mr Y if Si ≤ Sj and Bi ≥ Bj or if Si ≥ Sj and Bi ≤ Bj (if
>   both properties of Mr X are greater then corresponding properties of
>   Mr Y, he doesn't even notice him, on the other hand, if both of his
>   properties are less, he respects Mr Y very much).
>
> To celebrate a new 2003 year, the administration of the club is
>   planning to organize a party. However they are afraid that if two
>   people who hate each other would simultaneouly attend the party, after
>   a drink or two they would start a fight. So no two people who hate
>   each other should be invited. On the other hand, to keep the club
>   presti≥ at the apropriate level, administration wants to invite as
>   many people as possible.
>
> Being the only one among administration who is not afraid of touching
>   a computer, you are to write a program which would find out whom to
>   invite to the party.
>
> Input
>
> The first line of the input file contains integer N — the number of
>   members of the club. ( 2 ≤ N ≤ 100,000 ). Next N lines contain two
>   numbers each — Si and Bi respectively ( 1 ≤ Si, Bi ≤ 10^9 ).
>
> Output
>
> On the first line of the output file print the maximum number of the
>   people that can be invited to the party. On the second line output N
>   integers — numbers of members to be invited in arbitrary order. If
>   several solutions exist, output any one.

```
Sample test(s)

Input


4
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 2

Output


2
1 4
```

Basically my approach is:

1. First sort the array Strength[] with respect to Beauty[]
2. taking a array D[i] which store max lis till i
3. Optiomal solution  = `D(i) = { 1 + Max ( D(j) ) }` where `j < i` and `D[i] = max{ D[j] +1 }`for `j < i` and `Strength[j] < Strength[i]` and `Beauty[j] < Beauty[i]`  , if there is no such j then `D(i) = 1`

Am I missing anything in my approach?

My solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std; 
typedef struct {
    long int s;
    long int b;
} c_type;
int compare(const c_type &a, 
        const c_type &b) {
    return a.s < b.s;
}

int main( )
{


int n = 0;
cin>>n;
vector<c_type> ct;
ct.resize(n);
//vector<long int> b(n,-1);
//s[0] = 1;
//s[1] = 1;
//s[2] = 2;
//s[3] = 2;
//b[0] = 1;
//b[1] = 2;
//b[2] = 1;
//b[3] = 2;

vector<long int> d(n,1);
vector<long int> p(n,-1);
long int max = -1;
long int bestEnd = -1;
for(int i = 0 ;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>ct[i].s>>ct[i].b;
}
 sort (ct.begin(), ct.end(), compare);
for(int i  = 1 ; i < n ;i++)
{
    for(int j  = i-1 ; j>=0 ; j--)
    {
        if(((d[j] + 1) > d[i]) and (ct[j].b < ct[i].b) and (ct[j].s < ct[i].s))
        {
            d[i] = d[j]+1;
            p[i] = j;
        }
    }
    if(max < d[i])
    {
        max = d[i];
        bestEnd = i;
    }
}
cout<<max<<endl;
if(bestEnd != -1)
while(bestEnd not_eq -1)
{
    cout<<bestEnd+1<<" ";
    bestEnd = p[bestEnd];
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is LIS (longest increasing subsequence), your solution seems to be OK. Suppose you have implementation error? (you may post your solution here).

Comment: Your solution outputs incorrect indices for the persons. When you have sorted input, their ordering changed. Just store additional index into your structure and use it. However, you code will TLE, cause of O(N^2). You need O(NlogN) solution, which is classic one for LIS.

Comment: @juver You should post this as an answer. For OP, apart from what juver said, you also don't output correctly if maximum possible number of members that can be invited is one.

Comment: Everyone in this club hates themselves ;-)  (And consequently the largest number of people that can be invited to the party without a fight breaking out is 0.  *Rockin'.*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution outputs incorrect indices for the persons. When you have sorted input, their ordering changed. Just store additional index into your structure and use it. 

However, your code will get TLE, cause of O(N^2). You need O(NlogN) solution, which is classic one for LIS.

Comment: What does TLE and LIS mean?

Comment: LIS - Longest Increasing Subsequence, TLE - in context of online judges, Time Limit Exceeded

Answer (score 2):

So there is an interesting way to think about this problem geometrically. Imagine plotting a graph with S,B on the axis, and putting an x for every person. (Remove any duplicate points also i.e. if s=s and b=b you can just remove one of them).

Then every for each point/person, only points in the rectangle which is both lower and to the left are viable choices. So I can associate with every person a number representing the number of people who respect them. Call this number C.

This provides an admissible heuristic for an a* search. Starting with the root node in the top right, my "best" move is typically the one that has the highest C number, as that preserves the greatest number of options for later. Further, once I have found one root to the base of the tree, I only need to choose other branches if their C number is higher than the actual number of persons, so most of the tree will terminate quickly.

I suspect that this type of search is optimal on average, but it may have slow edge cases depending on the distribution of the points.

[image]

SO this demonstrates how it would work, you start with some root node, and on the first run it goes to the highest C number, when it terminates, it counts back up to provide an "answer", and therefore it only has to check branches where the C number is strictly greater than the current best answer. In this case, there are no such other branches.

Its easy to see intuitively that this can be very fast if the points are distributed uniformly in S and B, but it might be very slow if they are strongly clustered about y=x, as then you would not exclude branches very fast typically.

Comment: It has complete O(NlogN) solution, as mentioned in the comments under the author's question.

Comment: A search tree can be much faster than that on average. Though it may have very much worse edge cases.

Comment: Although constructing the C numbers might take NlogN anyway. :)

But it seemed like an interesting approach.